# JPA One to One relationship not being recognized

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have created to tables, `Projects` and `Templates`, each project can only have one template and vise-versa.

I added a unique foreign key of `ProjectId` to the templates table, but in `Eclipse` when I go to create entites from tables, it recognizes this as a `One-to-Many` relationship, but because the foreign key is unique, it is a `One-to-One` relationship.

How can I set up these tables so `JPA` recognizes it as a `One-to-One`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything in particular in your tables: simply create a foreign key between the two tables, then define in your entities the relationship as one to one: add to the property or the method the `@OneToOne` annotation. Here is a good [example](http://uaihebert.com/jpa-onetoone-unidirectional-and-bidirectional/) (both for unidirectional and bidirectional relationship).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Why is it not recognizing the relationship correctly?

Comment: When you create entities from tables usually the most common relationship will be implemented in your entities (in this case, a one to many relationship - Netbeans has the same behaviour...), update those entities manually after the automatic class creation.